# wrap set time out function around simple slide animation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a simple slide down function using jQuery where I'm simply animating an image to slide down. It works great. However I'm trying to reset the animation after it's ran, so it will continue on loop during the duration of the users session. I tried the below, but it didn't work as wanted, slide animation still ran, but not the sought effect of timing out and restarting. Thanks for any thoughts.

```
$(window).load(function () {
setTimeout(function(){
        $("#man").show("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 2000);
},500);
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to slide up then down then up and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function after it completes the 2000ms transition.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CqR9E/392/

```
$(window).load(function () {
   setTimeout( go(),500);
});

function go(){

  $("#man").show("slide", {
      direction: "up"
  }, 2000, function(){
     $( "#man:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
      go();
  });
}
```